# Symbol to method call

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to transform a symbol to a method call? I know it's possible for a String, but not for a symbol. I have this code in `conveyance.rb`:

```
def boats
  boats = []
  User.all.each{ |u| boats += u.boats}
  boats
end
def boats_nb
  self.boats.length
end
def cars
  cars = []
  User.all.each{ |u| cars += u.cars}
  cars
end
def cars_nb
  self.cars.length
end
```

I would like to know if there is a means to make a method like that:

```
def conveyances(:symb)
  c = []
  User.all.each{ |u| c += u.to_method(:symb) }
  c
end
def conveyances_nb(:symb)
  User.to_method(:symb).length
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) method:

```
def conveyqnces_nb(symb)
  User.public_send(symb).length
end
```

or, if you would like, [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send) might be suitable. The difference is that `send` allows to call private and protected methods, while `public_send` acts as typical method call - it raises an error if method is private or protected and the caller object isn't allowed to call it.

Answer (score 4):

Use the #send instance method

```
u.send(:symb)
```